# Iterable object as parameter in spring data rest api

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Hi I need to pass a json object in `POST` request of the SPRING DATA REST. Is it possible to pass directly and make it process with `save(iterable)` with any Jackson script or we have to use a Controller with `@RequestBody`and process the `Iterable`and save it using repository function??

Now I am doing,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "batchInsert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String batchInsert(@RequestBody List<Test> test){
testRepo.save(test);
return "loaded";
}
```

and implements `Serilizable in DAO object`and my doubt whether there is any default format to pass whole `json` without using any controller as `CRUD` operates normally. Please help me find solution. Am new to springs and I am unable to use the same url to get request in `spring-data-rest API`, if I use `batchInsert`in controller and in rest api. Fortunate to use different api calls now for inserting and searching purpose. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the consumable media type?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "batchInsert", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
```

It's quite common to pass JSON objects to Spring controllers, so it should work...

Comment: Actually its working as mentioned above itself. As of spring-data-rest, we dont require to write controllers, we can write DAO and use Repository interface and connect it with @RestResource, rest it will do its magics. So what I am expecting is, as far now I can send a json array without controllers and its saving. So without Controller, is it possible to pass jsonobject and as the CRUD Repository contains save(iterable), it will process the data. So that asked.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question at first. Never worked directly through Repository-@RestResource... Hope someone helps you!